# Machine learning algorithm for relative similarity

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I'm trying to find a good starting place (or existing algorithm) to determine the similarity of various items to one another based on subjective assessments of two items' relative similarity to a third.

These assessments are stored in a series of uniquely-identified transactions of the format:

> Reference Item, More Similar Item, Less Similar Item

These transactions are generated when a human "teacher" is presented with one random "reference" item and two other random items and then asked to select which of the latter two items best matches the reference item.

The set becomes a series of value judgments in the form: $A$ is more similar to $R$ than $B$ is to $R$. I reckon this approach is more implicit than querying the teacher for a number to represent the distance between items, but I've run into a roadblock when it comes to converting these relative judgments to absolute numbers to represent the distance between items.

What existing machine learning approaches best addresses this problem? Are there modifications that could be made to the data collection methodology which would improve the efficiency/accuracy of the algorithm?

Comment: Which kind of output do you want to have as a result? How many different items are we talking about? Are $A, B, R$ randomly selected from the same pool of items (without replacement, of course)?

Comment: @Roland The output should be a list of relations (i.e. distances) between each possible pairing of items ($A,B$ is the same as $B,A$). $A$, $B$, and $R$ are selected randomly from the same pool of items.

Comment: Could you expand on that 'list of relations'? What's the algorithm supposed to add to the bare list combinations of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Roland A numerical representation of the two items' similarity. This would enable a recommendation algorithm, for example, to produce a list of similar items given a single item.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that for the training set, given $R,A,B$, the choice which item is more similar, and which is less, is uniquely determined? How many different items are we talking about?

Comment: @Roland Yes, and the number of items may range in the thousands.